# Magento doesn't validate my select field

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, form-validation

I am using two custom extensions in my Magento checkout process. One that makes a nice onestep checkout without the different steps, and one that allows the customer to choose a pickup point for picking up their parcel.

However, the field yo choose the pickup point is not validated, when used with the onestep checkout. The field has class="required validate-select", but the page can easily be submitted without choosing anything in the field.

I can't really figure out where to look for the error, since I thought this was everything that is needed in order to validate a field. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You should contact the one page checkout extension developer for this. It's  impossible to figure out how the extensions are build without seeing the code.

Comment: Can we see the HTML code. And you should confirm that the default select option has a value of "" in order to confirm that it is actually blank… Also check for any Javascript errors

Comment: Please contact your extension developer.